# Singular points while differentiating a function with respect to another function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have $z(x) = \frac{df(x)}{dx}$ where $f(x)$ if a function of x. I'd like to have the derivative of $z(x)$ in respect to $f$:

$\frac{dz}{df} = \frac{\partial f'(x)}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{df}$

Usually I'd just exchange $\frac{dx}{df}=1/f'(x)$. However, I'm interested in this as part of some larger differential equation, so let's say I plug my initial starting conditions and get some solution using Runge–Kutta. At a certain point I'm going to get $f'(x)=0$ so the derivative above diverges. What happens after that point? Can I just continue taking more steps of the Runge–Kutta method without any considerations?

Comment: Depending on the context, the "derivative of $z(x)$ in respect to $f$" is either very poorly defined or even nonsensical...

Comment: Please elaborate on the origin of this problem, where do you go from the ODE to your question? Is this from some kind of implicit solution after separation of variables?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that $f$ has, at least locally, an inverse function $g$ so that $g(f(x))=x$ and $f(g(y))=y$, so that $g'(f(x))·f'(x)=1$ and $f'(g(y))·g'(y)=1$. Then
$$
\frac{d}{dy}\,z(g(y))=z'(g(y))·g'(y)=f''(g(y))·\frac{1}{f'(g(y))}=\frac{d}{dx}\,\ln(f'(x))\Big|_{x=g(y)}
$$
if indeed this is what you were aiming for.